# Create Alarm in terraform taking into account Category and Metrics Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using terraform to create different alarms in AWS. I have different metrics separated by Category and Metrics Name.
The issue I have is I don't know if I can use Category field in terraform to create the Alarm for the specific case.
This is an example about two metrics I have

```
Category           Metrics Name
--------------------------------
Error-Not-Found    Get-Api-Error
Invalid-Request    Get-Api-Error
```

I can use metric_filter_name to specify the name of the metric but I also need the category to create an Alarm for `Error-not-Found` category and another one for `Invalid-Request` category

is there a way to create an alarm taking into account Category field. I was searching in terraform doc but there is nothing about how to use category.

Comment: Use the category as a dimension?